# Tracking ad impressions (views) and preventing fraud

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been trying to create a little ad system which users place a peice of ad code on their own site. I'm sure this has been mourned over many times but its surprising how hard it is to find info. This is using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Javascript to track impressions and clicks and prevent impression and click fraud.

This is the code that would be placed on a publishers site:

```
<script>
    var gv = { siteId: 1 };
    (function (d, w) {
        function a() {
            var s = d.createElement('script');
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.async = true;
            s.src = 'gv.js';
            d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
        }
        if (w.attachEvent) { w.attachEvent('onload', a); } else { w.addEventListener('load', a, false); }
    }(document, window));
</script>
```

From there gv.js would make a call to get the ad JSON info and then display the ad and send another request to track that the ad has been viewed. However what is stopping a user from just refreshing the page constantly? One thing to note is users can be anonymous and not logged in this is a general public kind of thing.

Comment: Use session_id as the PK and you can use MongoDb as the storage.

Comment: @sza - that doesn't mean it will count as unique user

Comment: If you just want analytic data then you could use an analytic program to read IIS log files which would give you various details.  If you want to create one yourself, then you would track via SessionId and store this along with other data you want.

Comment: @AliK - Any recommended IIS readers that I should use?

Comment: You could try [this](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2009/06/iis-log-analyzer).  I personally wrote a program that parsed the log files into db and then had a web interface to show the analysis data.

Comment: I would record every single click and include `DateTime`, `SessionID`, `IPAddress`, `AdID`. Then wire up a little algorithm to extract unique clicks based on the recorded data... namely SessionID/IPAddress.

Comment: @AliK - does that solution have an API? I need to be able to display the stats on my site

Comment: @Ryan - I am not sure, as I have not used it myself but someone suggested it when I was working on something.  However, if I am not mistaken it is written in c# and you might be able to use the dll in your code.

Comment: Why dont you use Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

Comment: I've made some big edits, please see

Answer (score 2):

> I'm sure this has been mourned over many times but its surprising how hard it is to find info.

+1 I had problems finding the info too, all the solutions are listed here:

[Prevention methods for click fraud on advertisements and their implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810886/prevention-methods-for-click-fraud-on-advertisements-and-their-implementation)

*This is one of those awkward times when I "should" close as duplicate but cant due to the active bounty and its likely to be missed amoung all the comments*

Comment: Hmm kinda helps but I don't really understand the implementation...